# Why most linux executable files are ET_DYN types in android system

Tags: android, linux, elf

By reading ELF header of a binary file in android system, I find that most executable files under /system/bin are `ET_DYN`, i.e., shared libraries. For example, the `/system/bin/ls, lsmod, kill` files are typed `ET_DYN`. In my opinion, these files are executable, and should be `ET_EXEC` type. So my question is: in android system, why executable files from Linux OS are compiled to `ET_DYN` type?

Answer (score 1):

> i.e., shared libraries

They are not: they are position-independent executables.

Comment: Is there any way to distinguish executable files from shared libraries by ELF header?

Comment: @shijunzhao No, there isn't (at least not for `PIE` executables).

Comment: thanks for you reply. In android platform, I see that the interpreters for .so and exe are different, can I distinguish exe from .so by their interpreters?